# Nodejs mssql server connection throws an error

Tags: node.js, sql-server, tedious

I want to connect my mssql database from nodejs.
I am using sequelize and tedious module for this.
My connection configs like this

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    "mydb",
    "username", "password", {
    host:config_data.host,
    "dialect":"mssql",
    "port":1433
    dialectOptions: {
        instanceName: "MSSQLSERVER"
    },
  
},
);
```

When I tried to run script, it throws an error.

```
(node:14584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionError: Failed to connect to 192.168.10.220:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
```

I apply all steps in configuration manager.
Enabled TCP/IP
Started Server SQL browser
Added 1433 port to Firewall

There is also additional error when host is "localhost".(Currently writed IP address)

```
(node:13552) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 
- 4292:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_lib.c:1947:
```

[image]

I need to help, is there someone have any idea ?

Comment: Are you using Windows Authentication or SQL Authentication? The former does not use usernames and passwords

Comment: I am using SQL Authentication. What should I do?

Comment: Connect using SSMS with SQL Auth to test.  SQL Auth is disabled by default in SQL Server.

Comment: And has the login with that username been assigned permissions to connect (`CONNECT SQL`) as well as `db_datareader` role?

Comment: `ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol` suggests that the SQL Server is using an SSL/TLS protocol that Tedious doesn't support. Have you tried adding `encrypt: false` to your connection options?

Comment: This is the solution. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 5):

You need to set encrypt to false in your Sequelize inside options.

```
   const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    "mydb",
    "username", "password", {
    host:config_data.host,
    "dialect":"mssql",
    "port":1433,
    "options": {
        encrypt: false,
        enableArithAbort: false
    },
    dialectOptions: {
        instanceName: "MSSQLSERVER"
    },
  
},
```

);

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because of TLS protocol mismatch between Source & Destination server. In my case my App server was Ubuntu 20.04 & my SQL Server(Express 2012) was on Windows server. I also tried to downgrade TLS protocols on Ubuntu but nothing worked. So finally I disabled tls encryption in Sequelize.
Make sure options are given as expected by Sequelize

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  port: dbConfig.PORT,
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
  pool: {
    max: dbConfig.pool.max,
    min: dbConfig.pool.min,
    acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
    idle: dbConfig.pool.idle,
  },
  // The below options are important to supress ssl issue on
  // AWS EC2 ubuntu when db server is on windows. There is TLS protocol issue
  // Which by using these options we disable tls encryption
  dialectOptions: {
  // Observe the need for this nested `options` field for MSSQL
    options: {
      encrypt: false,
      enableArithAbort: false
    }
  }
});
```